# My spark code is not using all the executors available in Yarn aws EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I have written Spark code which runs locally. I have created a user defined function which needs to be applied on a dataframe created by cross-joining two tables read from local files.

Somehow the user defined function I'm applying is not using is not getting distributed. I have installed the required python packages on all nodes. Using `spark-submit` I have have specified the number of cores and memory. This is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("WordSimilarities").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1,1000)).map(imprts)

df = spark.read.csv('./FlightGlobal_distinct_operators.csv', header=False).withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'first').repartition(10)
df.cache()

df2 = spark.read.csv('./TRAC_distinct_operators.csv',header=False).withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'second').repartition(10)
df2.cache()

df3 = df.crossJoin(df2)
df3.write.saveAsTable("hello", format="parquet",mode="overwrite",location="/user/hive/hello/")
df3 = spark.sql("select * from hello").repartition(500)
print(df3.count())
df3.cache()
```

And the function i am applying

```
schema = StructType([StructField("col1", FloatType()), StructField("col2", FloatType()), StructField("col3", FloatType()), StructField(
        "col4", FloatType()), StructField("col5", FloatType()), StructField("col6", FloatType()), StructField("col7", FloatType())])
    allmethodUDF = udf(all_methods_scores, schema)
    finalDF = df3.withColumn("complex", allmethodUDF('first', 'second')).select(
        'first', 'second', 'complex.col1', 'complex.col2', 'complex.col3', 'complex.col4', 'complex.col6', 'complex.col7')
    finalDF.show()
```

And here are the packages I'm using applied on each node:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
import sys
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import numpy as np
import editdistance
import jellyfish
import fuzzy
import re
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import itertools


def all_methods_scores(original1, original2):
```

inside that function above all packages i am doing lot of iterations

The code for the function simply applied on each of the row taking multiple columns as inputs. All RDD blocks are at only one node.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too simple an answer, but did your repartition your data?  If you're reading from a single .csv file (as it appears you are doing), you will end up with a single partition.

Try running repartition() on your data:

```
df.repartition(100)
df2.repartition(100)
```

after reading the CSV files and see if this fixes your problem.

What is it that your parallelize() at the top of your code is doing?

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1,1000)).map(imprts)
```

Comment: imprts is function in python to that i am making sure that these packages are imported in each slave node by following
    def imprts(x):
          import numpy as np
          import editdistance
          import jellyfish
          import fuzzy
          import re
          from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
          import itertools
          return x

Comment: Here spark.sparkContext.parallelize(df)
df is dataframe not a list .. can we parallelize dataframe like this .
Actually that is the reason i tried with repartitioning the data.

Comment: You're correct.  I should have said "repartition(n)".  The parameter 'n' will need to be selected according to your available cores (I find 4-6x typically works well).  Regardless of whether you have an RDD or a dataframe, reading from a single file yields a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

To use all the available executors you need to specify **--num-executors <*value*>** in your spark-submit command.